# Cluster evolution over time

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I have a dataset of transactional data with customer ID and I want to segment the dataset into groups using cluster analysis. I'm interested in following the evolution of each cluster over time, but since customers have very different behaviours (roughly 50% of the time a customer will change cluster the week after), I was wondering what would be a statistically sound approach. Is it a good idea to train a clustering algorithm every week and look backwards at the weekly evolution of each segment?

Comment: Which clustering technique are you using to generate the clusters?

Comment: I used k-means but my question was not just limited to that.

Comment: k-means will work because the number of clusters is fixed. One option is to run k-means every week over the data. You will have generated time series which you can then analyze. For example, you could plot the size of your largest cluster over time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

1. Dynamic mode decomposition.
2. Dynamic Time Warping. Found a nice resource on [Towards data science blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-hierarchical-clustering-using-dynamic-time-warping-in-python-c8c9edf2fda5).

These two have proven better approaches than PCA for time series clustering.

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

May be what you were looking for is the [Rand index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index?wprov=sfla1) ?

This "is a measure of the similarity between two data clusterings", in other words, if the RI is close to 1 (after repeated clustering over a time window) then your segment are stable.

Answer (score -1):

Cluster once.

Study the clusters and refine them to define classes.

Then classify points to these classes.

Comment: Thanks. Any reference to dive deeper? My concern is whether clustering once 2 years of monthly data would yield different results than clustering each month separately and then looking at the results.

Answer (score -1):

Run Clustering periodically (say every month).
Use the elbow method to make a decision on the best number of clusters (be open to this aspect of the system changing over time).
Define / Label what each cluster represents - The centroids of each cluster represents the average behavior of the inmates within the cluster.